# Is it possible to interface R from Sagemath within an HTML document?

Tags: html, r, interface, sage

According to this document 
http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/r.html 
it is possible to use R syntax while running Sagemath. I'm new to Sage, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "interface"... does anyone know if there is a method to interface R while in an HTML document? The method described in the above link does not work (assuming I'm applying it correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [embed R in HTML using the Sage cell server](http://statisfactions.com/2013/interactive-r-code-widget/).  You can also switch to R mode in both the Sage notebook server and [SageMath Cloud](http://cloud.sagemath.com/).  I'm not sure if this answers your question.